# How to bring in percentages of this ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am finding it difficult to convert this plot using the counts in percentages. I tried using the mutate function. It did not work.

```
 data$Disease.diagnosis<-factor(data$Disease.diagnosis)

ggplot(s, aes(x = Disease.diagnosis))+
   geom_bar(aes(x =reorder(Disease.diagnosis,Number) ,y= Number,fill=Number),
               stat = "identity",show.legend = FALSE)+
  ggtitle("Graph representing symptoms observed by inhabitants")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=1))+coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Without data it is obvious that we can't test the code.
Please tell me.

First `mutate` from `dplyr` package `perc`, where `Number` of the elements are divided by all to get percentage.

Then replace `Number` by `perc` in your ggplot code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  mutate(perc = Number / nrow(data)) -> s

ggplot(s, aes(x = Disease.diagnosis))+
  geom_bar(aes(x =reorder(Disease.diagnosis,Number) ,y= perc,fill=perc),
           stat = "identity",show.legend = FALSE)+
  ggtitle("Graph representing symptoms observed by inhabitants") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=1)) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```